# Component unmounts when parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React 16.8.2, and I'm having a problem with children of my  component unmounting whenever state is changed in the app component.

Here's the scenario:

- I have App.jsx (a functional component) with a number of state variables (useState)
- The setters for some of these state variables are passed down the tree through a Context provider (useContext in the descendent)
- I have a menu component (descendent of app), that invokes these setters to (for example) show a modal dialog
- I have a modal dialog component (child of App), that uses the state variable as a property to determine whether it is open or not -- standard React stuff I think.

My problem: when any state variables in App are changed (through hooks of course), the children of App are unmounted and remounted- even if they have no connection to the state being changed. They aren't just re-rendered - the children are unmounted and their state is re-initialized. So the fields are cleared on my dialog, when they shouldn't be, for example.

This is already a fairly complex application, so I've spent a lot of time today isolating the problem. I then set up a simple create-react-app to try to replicate this behavior there - but this test app behaves like it should. Changing parent state, whether through a prop callback, or through a context-provided callback from the child - re-renders but does not unmount/remount and child state remains intact.

But in my real app, the components re-mount and child state gets re-initialized.

I've simplified it down to the barest that I can - I'm setting a fake state variable "foo" with "setFoo" through the Context from the child. Even though foo is not used by any component, changing the value of foo causes the children of App to unmount/remount.

In App.jsx:

```
const App = props => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false);
  // ...
  const appControl = {
    toggleFoo: () => setFoo(!foo);
  };
  // ...
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appControl}>
      ... a bunch of stuff not using foo anywhere
      ... including, deep down:
      <Menu />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In Menu.jsx:

```
const Menu = props => {
  const appControl = useContext(AppContext);
  // ...
  return (
    ... super simplified for test
    <div onClick={appControl.toggleFoo}>
      Toggle Foo
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I understand state properly, I do believe that changing state should result in children being re-rendered, but not re-mounted. This is what I'm seeing in my simple create-react-app test, but not in my real app.

I do see that I'm not on the latest React - perhaps upgrading will fix this?

Thanks for any insight on what I may be doing wrong, or misunderstanding here.

Comment: There's nothing in the code currently in your question that explains why the child components are unmounted. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Are you using the `key` attribute in some of the unmounted/remounted children or in some intermediate parent of them? If that is changes, it causes a remount.

Comment: @Tholle - I'm going to see if I can make a minimal, repeatable test. If I do, that will likely tell me what the issue is anyway... It's good to know that, based on what you see here, you concur that the components shouldn't be re-mounted. At least I know I'm understanding it correctly. I have tested my create-react-app test with 16.8.2, and it still works correctly. I was hoping it was just a React bug =)

Comment: @cbdev420 I'm not using key on any direct children of App. There are some places in the tree, rendered with map, that do use key.

Comment: That might be your problem. That's the only way I could think of React remounting things. The second think would be some change in `route`, but from what you described that doesn't seem to be the case. Take a closer look into that, and/or paste some more code on your question so we can look too.

Comment: I solved it (see answer below). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I describe strategies for determining if components are being remounted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70531948/200987

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved. This is an interesting one. Here's what happened.

In my App component, I had a fairly deep tree of HOC's. Due to some dubious decisions on my part, I ended up breaking App into two components. App and AppCore. I had a reason for it, and it seemed to make sense at 3am. But to be both quick **and** dirty, I stuck AppCore as a const, inside my App function. I remember thinking to myself "I wonder what problems this will cause?" Now I know. Perhaps a React expert can fully explain this one to me though, as I don't see the difference between JSX assigned to a constant, and JSX returned directly. But there clearly is, and this is simple to reproduce.

To reproduce, create-react-app a test app:

```
create-react-app test
cd test
```

Then replace the contents of App.js with:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Menu = props => <div onClick={props.click}>Toggle Foo</div>;

const Test = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
    return () => console.log("unmounted");
  }, []);
  return null;
};

const App = props => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false);

  // this is the root of the problem
  // move this line outside of the function body
  // and it mounts/unmounts correctly
  const AppCore = props => <Test />;

  return (
    <>
      <Menu click={() => setFoo(!foo)} />
      <AppCore />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Then npm start, and when you click on "Toggle Foo" you'll see that the Test component is unmounted/remounted.

The solution here, is to simply move AppCore out of the function body. In my real app, this means I have some refactoring to do.

I wonder if this would be considered a React issue?

Comment: The reason is that you've created a new lambda for `AppCore` each time the `App` function is called, i.e. each time the `App` component is rerendered. Of course, it will have no connection to the previously rendered component, forcing the previous one to unmount and the new one to mount.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. We had a similar problem and this answer help us a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had the same problem reproduced on the top of my components hierarchy causing nested re-rendering issues.

Comment: @Cerberus that would mean useCallback or useMemo could help keeping the reference to previous component. But somehow in my case it still remounted the component.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I was about to go crazy!

Comment: For some good strategies on identifying which components are being unmounted/remounted, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/70531948/200987

Comment: Just as @cerberus said, you're creating the component fresh on each re-render. You can get around this by wrapping it with a `useCallback` if you want a const still.

E.g.,
```
const AppCore = useCallback(props => <Test />, []);
```

The dependency list can be empty 'cause it doesn't appear to use any react state inside the anonymous function. In your real code if it depended on local state (e.g., `useState` variables) you'd need to add those to the dependency list.

Comment: I was struggling for the solution from yesterday. This solution worked now. Feeling like I have won world cup now :)

Comment: Helps solve a big problem driving me nuts.

Comment: Thank you, absolute lifesaver, this problem had been bugging me for a long time ... actually this issue (the fact that a child component was being unmounted and remounted) was causing an error within my custom hook which was trying to update the state of the component: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" - I moved the declaration of the child component outside of the parent component (i.e. outside of the "lambda") and voila, problem solved!