# How to determine if a component has been remounted?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-router

There are lots of threads on how to determine if a component has been unmounted, but very few of them are very useful if what you want to determine is if the component has been *remounted* - essentially clearing the state. I found [one thread describing my issue almost to the letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55606873/200987), but gave no good strategies to help me find the offending code.

What is a good way of determining that an unmount followed by a mount has taken place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I used to determine which component was being unmounted was to add a call to a debugging utility in each component. This is actual example output that very easily showed the culprit:

```
TopLevelRoutes: #useEffect cleanup
debugging-utils.ts:20 ClientsTopRoute: rendering (total: #74
debugging-utils.ts:5 ClientsTopRoute, seconds since last mount: 118
debugging-utils.ts:20 Clients/Listings: rendering (total: #371
debugging-utils.ts:5 Clients/Listings, seconds since last mount: 0
Clients/Listing: totalRenders 371
Listings.tsx:230 Clients/Listings: viewClientDrawer false
debugging-utils.ts:20 Clients/Listings: rendering (total: #372
debugging-utils.ts:5 Clients/Listings, seconds since last mount: 0
Listings.tsx:99 Clients/Listing: totalRenders 372
Listings.tsx:230 Clients/Listings: viewClientDrawer false
debugging-utils.ts:10 Clients/Listings: #useEffect cleanup
debugging-utils.ts:10 ClientsTopRoute: #useEffect cleanup
index.tsx:34 TopLevelRoutes count: 120
debugging-utils.ts:20 ClientsTopRoute: rendering (total: #75
debugging-utils.ts:5 ClientsTopRoute, seconds since last mount: 118
```

You can easily spot from this that the `Clients/Listings` components is being unmounted and mounted on every re-render of its parent `ClientsTopRoute`.

I got this by adding this to each suspected component:

```
import { createRenderingInfoPrinter } from "../debugging-utils";

const debug = createRenderingInfoPrinter("ClientsTopRoute");

const ClientsTopRoute: React.FC = () => {
  debug();
  return <div> ...</div>
```

The debug hook I created looks like this:

```
/* debugging-utils.ts */

import React from "react";

export function usePrintSecondsSinceLastMount(identifier: string) {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(0);
  console.debug(`${identifier}, seconds since last mount: ${seconds}`);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds + 1), 1000);
    return () => {
      console.debug(`${identifier}: #useEffect cleanup`);
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [seconds]);
}

export function createRenderingInfoPrinter(identifier: string) {
  let count = 0;
  return () => {
    count++;
    console.debug(`${identifier}: rendering (total: #${count}`);
    usePrintSecondsSinceLastMount(identifier);
  };
}
```

If you do not care about the total number of renders you can of course just use the `usePrintSecondsSinceLastMount` hook directly.

---

For completeness, my situation of unmounting was due to a inconspicuous looking bit of React Router code left by my predecessors:

The key here is that the HOC components created by `withRouter` are *re-created* on every re-render. Therefore, they do not share anything with the subtree of the previous VDOM and so an unmount of the existing node takes place. Simply extracting the HOC out of the render function, as `const Listing = withRouter(ClientsListingComponent)`, fixed the issue.

This situation is similar to the only relevant thread I could find on the matter where a JSX functional component was [created in the render phase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55606873/200987).